# 2 values have been recieved, a number and None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use 2 codes. I want program 1 to recieve the value from program 2.

file 1:

```
from OpenUSB import transmitter

def valuepullup():
    newval = transmitter()
    print(newval)


valuepullup()
```

file 2:

```
def transmitter():
    print (2)
```

result I get is:

```
2
None
```

I would love use the value which just got send over. As the current situation the None spoils it.
Is there a way to stop the none from coming with the 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The functions (implicitly) return `None`. You could just include a `return newval` (in `valuepullup`) and `return 2` (in `transmitter`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options here, either simply use a `return` instead of a `print` in your `transmitter` function, or just call your `transmitter` without calling `print`. What is happening here is that you are both printing the `return` of the function, which is `None` (because not specifying a return, will return `None` by default), and the `print` inside the function.

Observe:

```
>>> def transmitter():
...     print (2)
...
>>>
>>>
>>> transmitter()
2
>>> print(transmitter())
2
None
>>>
```

More closely to your example, look what happens when you assign `transmitter` to a value:

```
>>> newval = transmitter()
2
>>> print(newval)
None
>>>
```

So, with respect to your code, you should do

```
def transmitter():
    return 2
```

Which actually makes the code inside your `valuepullup` make much more sense. You are looking to actually store the `2` in `newval`. So, you *should* be returning the `2` from your `transmitter` function instead so that `newval` actually holds `2` now. As it stands in your code, it holds `None`, because it will hold the return of `transmitter`. Which, as explained, is `None`. So, your code would *now* be:

```
from OpenUSB import transmitter

def valuepullup():
    newval = transmitter()
    print(newval)

def transmitter():
    return 2

valuepullup()
```

Now, when you print `newval` it will in fact be 2.

Answer (score 1):

You did not return anything from `def transmitter():`. instead of printing 2, return 2.